# How to group a date by 5 days instead of the standard date_trunc by week

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am in need of grouping of dates by 5 day increments as opposed to a standard `date_trunc('week',date)` in order to do a `count(*)` on that grouping

Would anybody be able to help me with this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would get the minimum date, take the difference and divide by 5:

```
select ( datediff(day, min_date, date) / 5 )::int as period_num,
       count(*)
from (select t.*, min(date) over (order by date) as min_date
      from t
     ) t
group by 1;
```